# Do we need a .build() method in the Builder Pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, builder, effective-java

I had a question regarding the "Builder Pattern" covered in "Effective Java". Do we need a `.build()` method for it to correctly implement the pattern? For instance, let's say that we have the following class:

```
public class CoffeeDrink {

    private int numEspressoShots;
    private short milkType;
    private boolean withWhip;

    private CoffeeDrink() {
    }

    public static CoffeeDrink buildNewDrink() {
        return new CoffeeDrink();
    }

    public CoffeeDrink withEspresso(int n) {
        this.numEspressoShots = n;
        return this;
    }

    public CoffeeDrink withMilkType(shot t) {
        this.milkType = t;
        return this;
    }

    public CoffeeDrink withWhip() {
        this.withWhip = true;
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then how we use it:

```
CoffeeDrink c = CoffeeDrink.buildNewDrink()
                         .withEspresso(2)
                         .withMilkType(2)
                         .withWhip();
```

Would this still be valid if I don't have a static inner `Builder` class? I guess that one of the advantages is that it holds off from creating a new `CoffeeDrink` object until the method `.build()` is called, but I'm still creating a `Builder` object. Just seeking some clarifications.

Comment: The Builder Pattern is used to great advantage with immutable classes.  With them, the Builder is a mutable "helper" class that assists in the ultimate construction of the final product which is thereafter immutable.  Your example is merely a simple POJO and it shares the disadvantages of JavaBeans (mutable, can be viewed in an incomplete or inconsistent state, etc.).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, this is not the Builder pattern.  It's valid Java, and it will compile and run.  But your `buildNewDrink()` method, whether it's called `build()` or `buildNewDrink()` or something else, is just a simple Factory Method that creates a `CoffeeDrink`.  Those other methods are like setter methods that happen to return themselves.

The `static` nested Builder class is necessary.  While holding off on creating the class instance, it can perform validation logic to ensure that an invalid object is not created.  I'm not sure that there is an invalid state to a `CoffeeDrink` as you have it, but if it did, with your code, it would be possible to create a `CoffeeDrink` and have it in an invalid state after it was created, but before other methods were called.  The Builder pattern eliminates this possibility by validating the data before building the instance.  It also eliminates the need for constructor explosion, where lots of constructors with all possible combinations of parameters are needed, to cover all possible cases.

Comment: I agree with your remarks. These methods seem to be regular setters with *chaining*. Just a minor detail, but you might be missing a *"not"* in your answer, as in *"it can perform validation logic to ensure that an invalid object is **not** created"*.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. So would I validate all parameters in the builder function of the Builder class, before returning the instance of CoffeeDrink?

Comment: Yes.  The `build()` method is called last in the chain.  It validates all data previously passed in, and it creates and returns the desired instance.

Comment: The Builder pattern by the GoF (Gamma et al) has no `build()` method. It does say ConcreteBuilders provide `an interface for retrieving the product`, e.g., `GetMaze()` to return the maze that was build in steps. None of the sample code in GoF uses chaining. Many people use Builder differently than GoF. Their idea was to have directors that encapsulate all the build steps. The idea of "validating" is less important since the concrete builder is not code on the client but code controlled by the API provider inside the director.

Answer (score 4):

According to the GoF reference, `build()` isn't required. The original reference doesn't use chaining, and there is a `getResult()` step at the end of the `Director.construct()` method. The `Director` class takes care of encapsulating the build process, so `Client`s don't need to worry if they're building things correctly. It's the responsibility of the `Director`.

Here's the sequence diagram from the GoF reference on Builder:

[image: GoF Builder Sequence Diagram]